# iTerm2 startup command does not clear

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2

I tried setting a startup command on iTerm2 to remove the computer name and username from my terminal.

So I went to **Preferences** > **Profiles** > **General** and set **Send text at start** to "export PS1=”\W \$ “; clear;"

That didn't work so I cleared that field, however, now when I go to launch a new terminal window. I'm greeted with this.

[image]
I checked my ~/.bashrc and ~/.zshrc files respectively and both dont show this command, therefore it must be a bug with iTerm2. I also re-installed it and for some reason, it's still there.

Comment: Why don't you simply put it into your .zshrc file instead of doing it with iterm2 ? Just setting it in iterm2 won't add it to your configuration files.

Comment: Yes, I did that but this message still keeps popping up whenever I open a new window.

Comment: Which OS is this running on?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and then came to the realization that my default "Window arrangement" was always tied to the *last* session and therefore used a stale copy of my iTerm2 profile. The stale copy still had the startup command. So, I had to go to the "Arrangements" section of the iTerm2 preferences, delete my default arrangment. Start a new session by creating a new window, then went to the menu bar in the top: Window > Save Window Arrangment, and after saving set it as the default.

When I think about it, I suppose you could skip all the deletion of default arrangment that I mentioned first. Simply make a new window after you've started any iTerm session, and hopefully you won't experience the startup command—this hints that new windows don't attach to some session saved in your "default arrangment". Just save the window as a new arrangment and set is as the default